# Why aren't both alpha-carbons halogenated when acetone reacts with chlorine under UV?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, halogenation

My book shows the following reaction:

[image: Reaction between acetone and chlorine]

Why is only one alpha carbon halogenated? I googled, but couldn’t find anything on it.

Comment: UV light does not necessarily mean that the reaction is totally governed by a radical chain mechanism. The formation of HCl allows for acid-catalyzed chlorination. By either mechanism, the first chlorinated methyl reacts faster than the "naked" methyl.. With  this in mind, look at the stoichiometry of the reaction. Not enough Cl2 to form hexachloroacetone. Acetone can be perchlorinated given sufficient chlorine.

Comment: No, there is no stopping the hydrogen to get replaced with chlorine. Given enough chlorine, eventually all the hydrogen can get replaced to form hexachloroacetone. The formation of HCl helps and [using catalyst can be good in accelerating the reaction like pyridine or triphenylphosphine](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9745241B2/en). Some literature for you: https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v86-208 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243873792_Chlorination_of_Acetone_in_Gaseous_Phase_to_Mono-Chloroacetone_-_Process_Design_and_Simulation